# zoom image slider

Tags: jquery, slider, zooming

I want to get the zoom slider in my rails 3.1 application . Is there any demo available

Similer to this link?

[Zoom Slider](http://www.bluenile.com/three-stone-diamond-ring-platinum_5923?builder=BYOR)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For zooming the image , please try the link [Zoom image](http://andrew.hedges.name/experiments/pan-zoom/)

Answer (score 1):

Hiya **demo here** : http://jsfiddle.net/DV5GU/

I borrowed the image from the link you gave :P

also some helpful ideas reside here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/eW53L/ **&** here: http://jsfiddle.net/vcw8c/

**Jquery Code**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#image1').width(200);
       $('#image1').mouseover(function()
       {
          $(this).css("cursor","pointer");
          $(this).animate({width: "300px"}, 'slow');
       });

    $('#image1').mouseout(function()
      {   
          $(this).animate({width: "200px"}, 'slow');
       });
   });​
```